# Implementing Gauss Seidel iterative method on C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement the Gauss seidel Iterative method in C++. i have a very messy code because i am still learning. for some reason my while loop seems to run without implementing the loop at all. I cannot get do while to work either.
The test matrix im using is

```
     number of equations=2
     x[0][0]=4
     x[0][1]=2
     x[1][0]=1
     x[1][1]=3
     b[0][0]=1
     b[1][0]=-1
     accuracy=0.2
```

the loop should continue until K has become less than accuracy.
The results should be;

```
     x1=0.4583 
     x2= 0.4681
     (i printed the F matrix just to make sure that part was working correct)
     k=0.136
     iterations performed=2
```

Again sorry for the messy code, like i said i am still learning.
Also i've tested the maths on separate codes and it works perfectly.

```
int main()
{
int n,i,j,p=0,l=0;
cout<<"Enter number of Equations = ";
cin>>n;
double a[n][n],b[n-1][1],F[n-1][1],x[n-1][1],T[n-1][1],e,k,B,C;
cout<<"[a].[x]=[b]"<<endl;
cout<<"Enter Matrix a:"<<endl;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
for(j=0;j<n;j++)
{
    cout<<"a["<<i<<","<<j<<"] = ";
    cin>>a[i][j];
}
cout<<"Enter Matrix b:"<<endl;
for(j=0;j<n;j++)
{
    cout<<"b[0,"<<j<<"] = ";
    cin>>b[0][j];
}
cout<<"Enter the Accuracy = ";
cin>>e;
for (i=0;i<n;i++){
    T[i][0]=0;
}
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    x[i][0]=0;
}
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    F[i][0]=0;
}
    while (k>=e){
        C=0;
        p=p+1;
        k=0;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            B=0;
            T[i][0]=(b[i][0]/a[i][i]);
            C=a[i][i];
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (j!=i)
                    B=B+(a[i][j])*(x[j][0]);
            }
            x[i][0]=T[i][0]-(B/C);
            }
        cout<<x[0][0]<<endl;
        cout<<x[1][0]<<endl;

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            F[i][0]=F[i][0]+(a[i][j]*x[j][0]);
            }
            }
         for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            F[i][0]=(F[i][0]-b[i][0]);
        }
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            k=k+((F[i][0])*F[i][0]);
        }
        k=sqrt(k);
    }
for (i=0;i<n;i++){
cout<<"x"<<i+1<<"="<<x[i][0]<<endl;}

cout<<"number of iterations used: "<<p<<endl;
for (i=0;i<n;i++){
cout<<"F"<<i+1<<"="<<F[i][0]<<endl;}
cout<<"k="<<k<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Edit: i tried giving k an initial value and that goes infinitely and the pro gram crashes.
Heres are a run down.
The 3 important Matrixes are a,x and b.
a*x=b
each row is changed into an equation and solved for x(i) with initial value for all the position in matrix x to be 0.
after completing this for all values in matrix x the accuracy "k" is checked by function:   a*x-b=matrix F, All values of F are then squared, added and under root to get k which is checked against e.

the results are:

```
  x1=0                                                                                                                            
  x2=0                                                                                                                            
  number of iterations used: 0                                                                                                    
  F1=0                                                                                                                            
  F2=0                                                                                                                            
  k=2.96439e-323
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed what the actual results are compared to the expected ones, and also if you indented your code in the standard manner. And also, having your variable names be descriptive words rather than letters would help quite a bit, too.

Comment: On my phone just now so could be missing something, but can't see where you initialise `k`... (Prior to the outset of `while` loop)

Comment: i tried giving k an initial value but it loops forever then.

Comment: With `double a[n][n];`, where `n` isn't a compile time constant, you are declaring a variable length array. You can't do that in standard C++ (it's a C99 construct, only available as a non portable extension in some compilers), create a proper class or use some other standard container. Also, the others are declared too small, e.g. `b[n - 1][1]`, while all the loops go up to `n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First please note that the method you implement is the Jacobi iterative method, not Gauss-Seidel method.

There were several issues in your code:

- `k` was not initialized: it must me set to a large value before the `while` loop, and set to 0 prior the calculation inside this loop
- Some vectors were not initialized at the good size: `n-1` instead of `n`
- The `F[.]` vector should be reset to 0 at each iteration, not only at the start of the program

Moreover, I made some other modifications

- I replaced variable length arrays (not C++) by `std::vector`
- I replace `[n][1]` arrays by `[n]` vectors
- I tried to avoid some `i`, `j` global variables

Here is a working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

using std::cin, std::cout;

int main() {
    int n, p = 0;
    cout << "Enter number of equations = ";
    cin >> n;
    double e , k, C;
    std::vector<double> b(n), F(n, 0), x(n, 0), T(n, 0);
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> a(n, std::vector<double> (n));
    cout << "[a].[x]=[b]" << "\n";
    cout << "Enter Matrix a:" << "\n";
    for (int i = 0;i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cout << "a[" << i << ","<< j << "] = ";
            cin >> a[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout << "Enter Vector b:" << "\n";
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        cout << "b[" << j << "] = ";
        cin >> b[j];
    }
    cout << "Enter the Accuracy = ";
    cin >> e;

    k = 1e10;
    while (k >= e){
        p = p + 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            double B = 0;
            T[i] = b[i]/a[i][i];
            C = a[i][i];
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (j!=i)
                    B += a[i][j] * x[j];
            }
            x[i] = T[i]-B/C;
        }
        cout << x[0] << "\n";
        cout << x[1] << "\n";

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            F[i] = 0.0;
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
                F[i] = F[i] + a[i][j]*x[j];
            }
        }
         for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            F[i] = F[i]-b[i];
        }
        k = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0;i < n;i++) {
            k += F[i] * F[i];
        }
        k = std::sqrt(k);
    }

    cout << "Solution :\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << "x" << i << "=" << x[i] << "\n";
    }

    cout << "number of iterations used: " << p <<"\n";
    for (int i = 0; i< n; i++){
        cout <<"F" << i << "=" << F[i] << "\n";
    }
    cout << "Final error = " << k << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly now, Thank you.
F should be reset at every iteration, Damn i did not see that one.
I still don't get the logic with n variable arrays not working properly, but that just means i have a lot to learn.